# CSS Transform Rotate just squishes video

Tags: html, css, video

When I use

`.video {
  transform: rotateX(-50deg);
}`
All it does is squish the video as shown below:

[So it turns out I can't upload images yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qK1.jpg)

But that image shows that all the code only squishes it so it isn't as tall.  I thought it was supposed to make it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyX6q.png).  I don't really know, but is it something with my code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.video {
  transform: rotateX(-50deg);
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="video">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8I1sQlRiJdY" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 900px">Brother, where are the iframes?  And oats.</iframe> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that the video isn't the actual one, I've got it from an ip webcam, but it works fine so do not worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Really it does rotate in X axis, the problem is that you can't see very well the result,  change X by Y or Z and see that really change, the squishes is the effect of rotation in X axis.

**With another perspective:**

How I said you in the comment for your requirement you need to use `perspective` css.
Here an example:

[Link Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LpLnudb5/1/)

Comment: RotateZ works as it should, but X and Y do not change the perspective on my computer, just squish.  Does this have something to do with the fact I do not have a graphics card in my computer?

Comment: @CYB No, how I said you the squish is fine for X and Y rotation. Only that is difficult watch the effects, for convince you that really is rotating, make X or Y rotation to 90 degree and see that video disapears and when make 180 degree you can see the video invert.

Comment: @CYB get a sheet of paper and imagine that is a video and rotate it in X or Y axis, you will see that the effect is as if it squishes.

Comment: The thing is if I do this, the top appears closer together than the bottom (because it is further away).  That is what I want happening and what should happen, but it doesn't.

Comment: @CYB If you want to see what you say then you need to have another perspective. I will update my answer with perspective.

Comment: Thanks heaps dude.  Works now.

Comment: I would move this to chat, but I have no reputation sorry.  The video px in the css, what does that do?